# Matching Regular Expression in Javascript and PHP problem

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I can't figure out how to get the same result from my Javascript as I do from my PHP.  In particular, Javascript always leaves out the backslashes.  Please ignore the random forward and backslashes; I put them there so that I can cover my basis on a windows system or any other system.  Output:

```
Input String: "/root\wp-cont  ent\@*%'i@$@%$&^(@#@''mage6.jpg:"    
/root\wp-content\image6.jpg (PHP Output)
/rootwp-contentimage6.jpg (Javascript Output)
```

I would appreciate any help!

```
PHP:
<?php
$path ="/root\wp-cont  ent\@*%'i@$@%$&^(@#@''mage6.jpg:";
 $path = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\\\\\/\.-]/", "", $path);
 echo $path;
?>

Javascript:
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = "/root\wp-cont  ent\@*%'i@$@%$&^(@#@''mage6.jpg:"; //exact same string as PHP
var regx = /[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\/-]/g;
path = path.replace(regx,"");
document.write("<br>"+path);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're not escaping the backslashes in your JS string, which you should always do (even in PHP) if you mean a backslash.

Example:

```
var path = "/root\wp-cont  ent\@*%'i@$@%$&^(@#@''mage6.jpg:";
alert(path);
path = "/root\\wp-cont  ent\\@*%'i@$@%$&^(@#@''mage6.jpg:";
alert(path);
```

Comment: @Frankie: Since I see that you are new here I just want to let you know that there is an answer checkbox to the left here, click that for the answer you are happy with. :)

Comment: +1. PHP is forgiving (read: confusing) about backslashes in string literals.  As Qtax said, do yourself a favor and escape them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Qtax is correct, then you can use this:
`var regx = /[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\/-\\]/g;`

Comment: No need to escape the dot in the char class.